# Android Material Design: How to set the touch target size of a Toolbar action button?

Tags: android

Reading this section

http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size

So in my tool bar I have buttons

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/info" android:title="info"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:orderInCategory="200" app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/map" android:title="map"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:orderInCategory="300" app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

How would I go about setting the touch target size? All these action buttons have to be 48 by 48 dp

But as I understand the dimensions of the action buttons

1. 18x18 (MDPI)
2. 24x24 (HDPI)
3. 36x36 (XDPI)
4. 48x48 (XXHDPI)

So how can I set a 48dp touch target size for an MDPI image?

Please help

Comment: For the toolbar it automatically selects the correct size.

Comment: @EugeneH, No I am asking how do I set a touch target size of 48 dp as the guidelines say because there is no XML attribute for the menu item of padding or size etc.

Comment: So you want to choose the size for an Image?

Comment: @EugeneH Kind of, I just want to achieve what the guidelines I linked to is suggesting. I am confused because the MDPI would be 18x18 so how would I have a 48dp target

Comment: You are confusing me lol. Give me an example so I can understand better

Comment: @EugeneH, how would I implement the touch target size of 48x48dp in the link mentioned above for an image that is sized 18x18px

Comment: I get what you mean.  I will post the answer below. Do you want an image button or imageView

Comment: @EugeneH Thanks, lets start with image view.

Comment: Just updated the ImageView.  I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or are you trying to add those buttons you have said above into a toolbar or actionbar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add the buttons into the toolbar as I defined in the menu XML file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78655/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-john-carter).

Comment: If the menu buttons are in the toolbar it automatically sets it to the correct dp for Material design guidelines.

Comment: @johncarter can you please tell the solution now?

Comment: @M.S. According to Eugene H, it automatically does it. But the way i see it is 48x48 dp is 36x36 (ldpi), 48x48 (mdpi),72x72 (hdpi) and 96x96 (xhpi) so just make sure the icons are these sizes, i think

Answer (score 0):

ImageView making it clickable.

> The Image is 18 x 18 dp.
>
> The view is 48 x 48

Finding the padding.  (48 - 18) / 2 = padding

```
<ImageView
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```